# Enabling SQLite Foreign Keys without command

Tags: sqlite, delphi, command, firedac, anydac

Is there a way to enable the SQLite Foreign Keys with the TFDQuery component and without using a sql command?

I build a SQLite DB with foreign keys and it works, also without enabling that option. However, I might better use it.

---

LuMa

Comment: What are you asking? I don't understand what "enable the SQLite Foreign Keys" means for you....

Comment: Sorry if wasn't very clear. SQLite docu says: "{ ... }  it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the PRAGMA foreign_keys command." 

Instead of using     PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;    command,
is there way to enable this with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to enable foreign key enforcement by default with the [SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS compilation option](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#default_foreign_keys), but this would require recompiling the database (driver).

Otherwise, you have no choice but to execute an SQL command.